# How to target elements loaded with ajax with .on

Tags: jquery, wordpress

It seems like Wordpress loads its widget form input fields with AJAX and thus I can't target anything it loads on document ready. I've read that .on is how to rebind events and I have played around with it, but I can't seem to get it down. How would I use .on in the following example? And, is it the only thing needed?

This gets loaded into the widget form:

```
<fieldset id="fieldradio">
    <legend>pick</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Yes" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="No"  />
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="field1" style="display:none;">
    <legend>this is field 1</legend>
    <input type="text" name="fdsa" value="value1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="fdsa" value="value1" /><br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="field2" style="display:none;">
    <legend>this is field 2</legend>
    <input type="text" name="asdf" value="value2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="asdf" value="value2" /><br />
</fieldset>
```

And this is the javascript I want to use:

```
jQuery("input[name=radiobutton]").change(function(){          

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "Yes") {
        jQuery("#field1").fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#field1").hide();
    }    

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "No") {
        jQuery("#field2").fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#field2").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated from one of static parents of the element or document object, you can use `on` method.

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name=radiobutton]", function(){  
      var ind = $(this).index('input[type=radio]');
      $('fieldset:gt(0)').hide().eq(ind++).show()   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MaNkE/

---

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name=radiobutton]", function(){  
     var ind = $(this).index();
     $('#field1, #field2').hide().filter('#field'+ind).show()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35tpE/

Comment: Thanks! Your code works great on fiddle but when i try it on wordpress it's a little quirky. First of all, i had to change gt(0) to gt(1). And when a radio button is selected they disappear. Hm.. not sure how to solve that one. I don't wish for the radio buttons to go away. Just the fieldset it's connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [examples](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the documentation.  This is the syntax you want:

```
jQuery("body").on("change", "input[name=radiobutton]", function(){         
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

That is `$("container").on("event", "selector", handler);`

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it doesn't seem to work to show/hide the input fields. I can do other things, like alert a message on change. But I can't target #field1 and #field2.

Comment: @John That could be because there are multiple elements with ID "field1", etc (I can't think of another reason).  But if it's the parent element, you could also use the JQuery `parent` selector.